# Function in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have to Do this

My array

```
array(
   0 => A,
   1 => B,
   2 => C,
   3 => D,
   4 => E,
   5 => F
)
```

I have array value for example Take C

is there any function available in php in that function i pass this value C and they give me array like this

```
array(
   0 => C,
   1 => D,
   2 => E,
   3 => F
)
```

the passing value and after another value is give me in array

Comment: To clarify, you want a function that takes an array and a value, and returns a new array with all items which appear *after* the value you've provided? I don't think this exists natively in PHP, but it should be trivial to implement...

Comment: Ok thanks to inform that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_slice()` in coordination with `array_search()`

Check out documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php and here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    0 => A,
    1 => B,
    2 => C,
    3 => D,
    4 => E,
    5 => F
);

$output = array_slice($arr, array_search('C', $arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rang like this:

```
$alphas = range('C', 'Z');
```

where C is your character you want your array start, if you want array from C to F:

```
$alphas = range('C', 'F');
```

output will be `Array ( [0] => C [1] => D [2] => E [3] => F )`

Comment: but i dont know last value of array

Comment: he doesn't need a set of consecutive values. He needs to slice the array starting from a specified value. This is too more specific case answer. The answer must be generic

Comment: OP didn't mention that the array will have the whole alphabet

Comment: This implies that the OP know the start and end point, however, OP mentioned that they only know starting point, check OP's comment "but i dont know last value of array"